# Angular 2 default app (ng -cli) getting compiled but not rendered

Tags: angular, rendering

Below are the versions of **NPM**, **Angular** and **Node** which are running on my machine.

```
@angular/cli: 1.2.0
node: 6.9.5
os: win32 ia32
@angular/animations: 4.2.6
@angular/common: 4.2.6
@angular/compiler: 4.2.6
@angular/core: 4.2.6
@angular/forms: 4.2.6
@angular/http: 4.2.6
@angular/platform-browser: 4.2.6
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.2.6
@angular/router: 4.2.6
@angular/cli: 1.2.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.2.6
@angular/language-service: 4.2.6
```

> C:\Releases\DTP\Experiance\angular-tour-of-heroes-master>npm -v
>   5.0.4

I have downloaded the tour of Heros app and ran the `nmp i` command, for which I got successful output. Then I ran the Angular `ng serve` command.

I don't see any errors in the console, none in Chrome's **'Network'** logs, but still I don't see the page inside the browser.

I have to mention that I am new to angular and this is my first app. Just now I tried rendering with Chrome's debug console and found this issue:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function common.es5.js:3062
(anonymous function) common.es5.js:3062
combine common.es5.js:3062
webpackJsonp.../../../common/@angular/common.es5.js common.es5.js:2912
__webpack_require__ bootstrap 7034ec41c5e0cfa2926c:54
webpackJsonp.../../../platform-browser-dynamic/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic.es5.js http.es5.js:2183
__webpack_require__ bootstrap 7034ec41c5e0cfa2926c:54
webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/main.ts environment.ts:8
__webpack_require__ bootstrap 7034ec41c5e0cfa2926c:54
webpackJsonp main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ bootstrap 7034ec41c5e0cfa2926c:54
webpackJsonpCallback bootstrap 7034ec41c5e0cfa2926c:25
(anonymous function) main.bundle.js:1
```

Comment: Where did you download it from?

Comment: I downloaded those from official sites only as a zip packages on my machine , and configured them manually . earlier my apps use to work but post upgrade of npm my (package download time issue if fixed ) but getting this wired one

Answer (score 0):

the only way out to fix this is to get these reinstalled .I did reinstall of node cache and it worked - however I was facing issue with slow downloads of node-cahce library's which got resolved post node / npm upgrade .